# I want to convert this nested list into a set

Tags: python, list, set

I want to convert this nested list into a set:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

What I've tried:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = set(a)
print(b)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Caitlin/Desktop/p.py", line 2, in <module>
    b = set(a)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Desired result:

```
{[1, 2], [3, 4]}
```

Can someone tell me a basic way to how it's done?

Comment: You cannot achieve your desired result. Did you mean that you wanted: `{(1, 2), (3, 4)}` instead?

Comment: lists are mutable objects.. they can't be hashed. So, this can't be done